# What does the definition mean by here?

Tags: real-analysis

I found a definition that,

Let $p, q > 0$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, $\|x\|_p$ is defined as:
$$\|x\|_p = \max_{||z||_q \leq 1} z^T x$$

What does this definition mean? What is the relationship of this definition with the one I found on wikipedia,

$$\| x \| _p = ( |x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \dotsb + |x_n|^p ) ^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Comment: What is meant by $\|z\|_q$ in the definition of $\|x\|_p$? You don't want to get caught in a definitional circle.

Comment: @UmbertoP. That's why I got confused about this.

Comment: @xxx222 Where did you find this?

Comment: I second @TheGeekGreek 's question. Where was this definition written? By the way, your stated conditions on $p$ and $q$ require that $p,q > 1$.